# What does :2:NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc in ctex-fontset-ubuntu.def mean?

Tags: fonts

I see such a paragraph in the `ctex-fontset-ubuntu.def` file which is related to zhmCJK.

```
    \ctex_zhmap_case:nnn
      {
        \setCJKmainfont { :2:NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc }
          [ BoldFont = :2:NotoSerifCJK-Bold.ttc, ItalicFont = gkai00mp.ttf ]
        \setCJKsansfont { :2:NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc  }
          [ BoldFont = :2:NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc  ]
        \setCJKmonofont { :2:NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc }
          [ BoldFont = :2:NotoSerifCJK-Bold.ttc ]
        \setCJKfamilyfont { zhsong } { :2:NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc }
          [ BoldFont = :2:NotoSerifCJK-Bold.ttc ]
        \setCJKfamilyfont { zhhei  } { :2:NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc  }
          [ BoldFont = :2:NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc  ]
        ……
       }
```

This may have nothing to do with my usage, but out of curiosity I would like to ask what the `:2:` here means? I guess it's the font weight, but I haven't found the relevant documentation after searching for a long time.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ttc` font files contain a collection of multiple fonts, so in addition to passing the file name you have to indicate which font in the file should be selected. In the case of noto-cjk, the different fonts contained in the same file are language variants. What you see here is the notation to select the font with index 2 in uptex, which is the simplified chinese version. The equivalent notation with fontspec would be `\setmainfont [FontIndex=2] { NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc }`